# deleting the file (FileInfo) in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

in my page. when i upload image i did image management. after that i want to delete the original image but i am getting error that the file is already using, like below 
**(The process cannot access the file 'D:\sasiweb\myimage\Images\jalsa.jpeg' because it is being used by another process.)**

and this is my code

protected void sizeManage(string filename)
    {

```
    string fn = Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + filename );

    System.Drawing.Bitmap newimg = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(fn);
    int h = newimg.Height;
    int w = newimg.Width;

    if (w > 100)
    {
        objJpeg = new ASPJPEGLib.ASPJpeg();
        objJpeg.Open(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + FileUpload1.FileName.ToString()));

        int L = 100;
        objJpeg.Width = L;

        objJpeg.Height = objJpeg.OriginalHeight * L / objJpeg.OriginalWidth;
        objJpeg.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + "small" + FileUpload1.FileName));

        string path = Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + FileUpload1.FileName.ToString());
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
        file.Delete();


    }
    else
    {

    }


}


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + FileUpload1.FileName.ToString()));
    sizeManage(FileUpload1.FileName.ToString());

}
```

i am getting error at file.delete();

**(The process cannot access the file 'D:\sasiweb\myimage\Images\jalsa.jpeg' because it is being used by another process.)**

Comment: some programmers sent the answer but it is getting same error again

Comment: (re the moderator flag you raised on your own post; the moderator flag feature is for administrative issue, site abuse, etc - not for regular question requests)

Comment: It could be that the previous object that held on the file was still in memory some time before the .NET garbage collector came along and removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to close

```
objJpeg
```

to do this operation.

Since the file is opened using objJpeg object it has to be freed to delete the file.

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + FileUpload1.FileName.ToString());
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);

objJpeg.Close(); // release the resources held by the object
file.Delete();
```

or you can code file open process in the using statement.

Comment: sorry same problem i am getting

Answer (score 1):

Does ASPJPEGLib.ASPJpeg() implement IDisposable? If it does then you should dispose it after saving. Easiest way would be to wrap it in a Using statement eg.

```
        using (objJpeg = new ASPJPEGLib.ASPJpeg())
        {
           objJpeg.Open(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + FileUpload1.FileName.ToString()));

           int L = 100;
           objJpeg.Width = L;

           objJpeg.Height = objJpeg.OriginalHeight * L / objJpeg.OriginalWidth;
           objJpeg.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + "small" + FileUpload1.FileName));
        }

        string path = Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + FileUpload1.FileName.ToString());
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
        file.Delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must close the file.
...

```
    objJpeg.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + "small" + FileUpload1.FileName));
    objJpeg.Close();
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + FileUpload1.FileName.ToString());
```

...

Comment: sorry same problem i am getting